# How to get city, state, and country name just by city name as Linkedin?

Tags: android, string, api, geolocation

I am working on an android project and now I am about to add a feature to get user location by asking the user. So I want an API for this, where we just write city name and get the city, state, and country name in String type as LinkedIn do. So I want to know that what is the best free API for this.
[image]

Comment: [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete)

Comment: [geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) can help you too